# Yii2 Api user validation with query string

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I m very new to Yii2 and i m trying to built a API with Yii2 . 
I have done with basic API code, and its working fine for me.
And i am trying to do the  username password validation , that work for me with

```html
public function behaviors()
  {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
      'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
      'authMethods' => [
        [
          'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),      
          'auth' => function($username, $password)
          {
            $out = null;
            $user = \api\modules\v1\models\User::findByUsername($username);   
            if($user!=null)
            {
              if($user->validatePassword($password)) $out = $user;
            }
            return $out;
          }
        ],        
      ]   
    ];
   return $behaviors;
  }
```

but this working with post action with browser pop up or in postman with Baseauth.

But i am trying to do the same with query string 
like : http://localhost/api/userauth?username=xxxx&password=xxxx
to return the access-token.

can you please help on this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea. `GET` parameters are logged by your webserver so the credentials are available in plain text to anyone with access to the logs. Use POST instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But i have to give the URL to third party, So they have to use in the code , that's y thought of doing like that.

Comment: The 3rd party should be able to use POST to send the parameters, it's a standard way of doing things even when dealing with 3rd parties.